# Any advantages to DisplayPort daisy-chaining compared with connecting monitors separately?

Tags: graphics-card, multiple-monitors, displayport

If I want to drive two or three monitors and my video card has enough DisplayPort outputs to connect each monitor separately, is there any reason I would want to daisy-chain the monitors with DisplayPort connections instead?

Answer (score 3):

None, outside needing fewer/neater connections. This might be handy for cable management, or simply making the most out of fewer ports on a video card with a monitor that allows for daisy chaining

You wouldn't see any disadvantages outside "edge cases" - for example, you'd either lose out on refresh rates or resolution *if* you're looking at say 120hz or UHD displays.

Displayport 1.2 will go up to U2160p/60 on a single monitor but the refresh rate is halved to 30 if you daisy chain. I'm unsure how refresh rates would be affected at lesser resolutions.